# Pause Spark Kafka Direct Stream

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

I have following code that creates a direct stream using Kafka connector for Spark. However I want to handle a situation, where I can decide that this streaming needs to pause for a while on conditional basis, is there any way to achieve this?
Say my Kafka is undergoing some maintenance, so between 10AM to 12PM stop processing, and then again pick up at 12PM from the last offset, how do I do it?

```
final JavaInputDStream<KafkaMessage> msgRecords = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jssc, String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class,
            KafkaMessage.class, kafkaParams, topicsPartitions,
            message -> {
                return KafkaMessage.builder()
                        .
                        .build();
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- Stop the spark context (from a separate time-monitoring thread) during those times that you want processing to be stopped and start them back up when you need processing to resume. This is best suited for large intervals (on the order of hours). This is the most *efficient* in terms of Spark utilization so you would not be uselessly occupying slots in the Spark cluster.
- Retrieve the spark batch time for your transformations, and conditioned on the batch time, decide whether or not to proceed to the rest of the transformation. Unfortunately, fetching the Spark batch time is not trivial; it's available if you change the DStream API to input the batch time as part of the transform API.